# How do aperture and the tilt portion of a tilt shift lens relate?

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field, tilt-shift

I have found that you can use the tilt feature of a tilt shift lens to do some pretty neat things with depth of field. I can throw it 8° to the right and everything on the left side of the image drops out of focus, along with a narrow band on the far right side. I also understand that a large aperture will narrow the range of areas in an image that are in focus. So do the two relate? If I have a larger aperture tilt shift lens, will that multiple the effect of a 8° tilt?

I am sorry for noting this, but I am not a math person and would prefer any simplified version of the science portion if at all possible, but feel free to include any equations if that will help others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing aperture has the same overall effect on depth-of-field with a tilted lens that it has on an untilted lens.

Tilting a lens changes the visible consequences of any change in aperture because it (when viewed sideways) changes the shape of the in-focus area from a rectangle to a wedge (with the point towards and above or below the camera, depending on tilt direction). The diagrams on [this](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/tilt-shift-lenses2.htm) page include some good visualisations of the effect.

decreasing/increasing the aperture (increasing/decreasing f-number) effectively causes the width of the base of the wedge  to increase/decrease accordingly. This results in the effect of the change in aperture becoming progressively smaller close to the point.

Comment: Awesome thanks Steven! The link helped a great deal as well!